# Custom bootstrapper as single instance

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, wix3.7, burn

I have a custom bootstrapper (Bootstrapper - Setup.exe and Custom BA library - CustomBA.dll) which can be started as multiple instances.

To allow the user to only open one instance, I tried checking the ProcessName in the Custom BA library. I am able to check for the ProcessName(Setup.exe) but it does that for the first instance itself and exiting the Custom BA does not close the Setup.exe.

**Is there a inbuilt WiX way to check the instance in the Bootstrapper itself?
If not, is there a way to check it in the Custom BA library?**

Comment: You need to get your process's Id instead of name. There might be multiple Setup.exe running, but each got a unique Id. Try with GetCurrentProcessId function.  See details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683180(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you use C++ custom bootstrapper you can try to create named mutex and check if this mutex exists. In my installer I do this check in UI thread. In such case second copy of installer closes silently without any error messages.

Comment: You'll want to be very careful that your mutex doesn't prevent upgrades from happening. You'll want to condition on being an upgrade or condition to block the same bundle id.